# Is it possible to create a protobuf-net serialization assembly for Silverlight and .NET?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I wonder if there is a tool like sgen for protobuf-net...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't finished the tooling in that area, but note that RuntimeTypeModel has a Compile() method that takes a path and type name; this is the method you want. I suggest trying this from a "full" .NET console application
 to generate the ell then reference that from SL (also referencing the ***SL*** build of the protobuf-net dll).

You might get an IDE warning about the reference, but from memory it should work. Long term I suspect I need to switch to the IKVM emit (to explicitly target SL), and *either way* I need to build an exe to do this for you automatically (presumably using some pattern to find a method to generate your RuntimeTypeModel through code).

Once you have that reference you can use the model you named when generating it; `new` this up and away you go.

Note that when using this approach, you can't serialize against private members - the runtime will not allow it.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, though I do not understand how a .NET assembly can be loaded by the Silverlight runtime and be run in the browser...

Comment: @mark it *could* be I'm thinking of the WP7 experience, then - in which case you might need to wait for me to swap in IKVM before getting a *clean* SL pre-generated version

Answer (score 0):

not sure i got your question right, but we use [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which creates CS files for us when we give proto files

Comment: I am using it as well. However, I do not have any .proto files. Rather I utilize the attributes and RuntimeTypeModel. In my case, protobuf-net is used as serialization engine and as such I compare it against the XML serialization engine. The latter has a tool to create the serialization assembly. I wish to know whether the same is possible with protobuf-net.